# Redimensionar img dentro de uma div

Tags: html, css, div

Olá, tenho  um site que tem postagens... e em algumas postagens coloco imagens nelas, porém estas imagens não ficam responsivas! e não tem como mudar a class dela para uma class responsiva... pois essas publicações são pegas de um banco de dados por $variaveis já tentei por meio do css isto:

```
.welcome-content > img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;    
   }
```

porém sem sucesso... alguém pode me indicar algum modo de sempre que tiver uma "img" dentro da div "welcome-content" ficar responsiva? tipo, deixar uma imagem responsiva eu sei!! porém quero que todas as imagens que estiver na div "welcome-content" que no caso, não teram uma class ficarem responsivas.

Minha div está assim:

```
<div class="welcome-content" align="left">
        <?php if($descricao != null){?><p class="descricao"><?php echo $descricao;?></p><? }?>

        <?php if($imagem != null){?><p><img src="<?php echo $imagem;?>" class="foto"/></p><? }?>

        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-hidden="true"></span> Postado em: <?php echo $data." às ".$hora;?> <br>
<?php if($postador != null){?>Postado por: <?php echo "$postador";?> <img src="https://minotar.net/avatar/<?php echo $postador?>/20"></p><? }else{
    echo "<p>Postado por: não informado</p>";
} ?>

    </div>
```

e meu css :

```
.welcome-content { 
    background-color: #fff;    
    padding: 5px 20px; 
    padding-bottom: 10px; 
}

.welcome-content > img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto; 
}
```

Comment: Como está o HTML dessas imagens? Poste na pergunta que facilita bastante analisar o problema.

Comment: A propósito, já tentou usar `!important`? Tipo: `max-width: 100% !important;`

Comment: Já, sim........

Comment: Essa classe `foto` faz oq?

Comment: O seletor está errado. O correto seria `.welcome-content p img{`

Comment: Ela não faz nada. Alias nem era pra estar ali.

Comment: A imagem está dentro de um `p`

Comment: Nossa.. eu nunca iria ter reparado! Obrigado!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está usando o seletor errado:

```
.welcome-content > img
```

Veja que a imagem está dentro ainda de um parágrafo `<p>`, logo teria que ser:

```
.welcome-content p img
```

Comment: Obrigado mesmo! já irei aceitar a resposta, tenho que esperar 2 minutos.

Comment: Obg amigo! Deus lhe pague!